# Hive with Hadoop high availability

Tags: hadoop, hive, high-availability

I wanted to understand how hive knows which of the hadoop namenode is in active state and what happens when the active namenode fails

Answer (score 1):

Hive is configured via `metatool` to point to the configured `dfs.nameservices` for HA HDFS.  See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+MetaTool.  `dfs.nameservices` is a logical address while the actual namenodes are configured with `dfs.ha.namenodes.[id]`.

As for which Namenode is active, state is stored in Zookeeper.  When the active namenode fails, failover is triggered after a configured time (5 second default, `ha.zookeeper.session-timeout.ms`).  A fencing script is required and triggers the standby namenode to become active.

Answer (score 0):

In hdfs HA environment name node url should be a logical name (eg hdfs://logicalnamenode). We need to configure hive to work with HA. For that you need to change the hive name node configuration with metatool command.

1. List the current NN configuration 
   **~# metatool -listFSRoot** 
   hdfs://namenode:8020/user/hive/warehouse
2. The following command will update the old NN configuration with Logical name

   **metatool -updateLocation hdfs://logicalnamenode hdfs://namenode:8020 -tablePropKey avro.schema.url**